# How to deserialize strange JSON format in C#

Tags: c#, json

I have this JSON response from a server:

```
"{\"Data\":[{\"AI\":\"(00)103002310000531111\",\"BatchId\":157,\"LogisticLevel\":7,\"ParentId\":-1,\"State\":1,\"SyncState\":-1,\"InternalID\":86996,\"ModifyReason\":null,\"AggregationDate\":\"1900-01-01T00:00:00\",\"CommissioningDate\":\"1900-01-01T00:00:00\",\"DecommissioningDate\":\"1900-01-01T00:00:00\",\"NumberOfChildren\":0,\"RejectCode\":-1,\"ShippingDate\":\"1900-01-01T00:00:00\",\"TotalNumberOfUnits\":1,\"CompanyPrefix\":\"030023\",\"FilterValue\":7,\"PackLevel\":1,\"ReferenceCode\":\"\",\"Schema\":1,\"SerialNumber\":\"1000053111\",\"IsGood\":true,\"Children\":[]}],\"Code\":10,\"Message\":\"Data retrieved\"}"
```

[image]

My responsbody it's wrong...much slashes...why ?

I serialize data with Newtonsoft JSON.
But the format isn't correct, I receive an error while deserializing on the client.
I saw that there're slashes in the JSON string. How can I solve this?
I use C#.

Comment: The backslashes are *probably* just the debuggers way of showing strings, can you try writing the string to a file and see if they are actually present?

Comment: If you saw an error - please add the error message to your question. It helps us tremendously understanding your problem.

Comment: There's nothing strange about that string. It doesn't contain any slashes, it contains double quotes. It deserializes just fine with JsonConvert or JObject.Parse. Are you trying to deserialize it to an object that *doesn't* match the schema perhaps?

Comment: The string shown in the question **doesn't contain slashes**. Not a single one. It really doesn't, ***assuming it is a C# string literal***. What looks like slashes are all escape characters, i.e. `\"` ==> `"`

Comment: "I receive an error while deserializing on the client." The error is what? The code you use to deserialize is what?

Comment: @DragandDrop I read that with an angry German accent in my head - was that intended?

Comment: Understandable - The "z" you've strewn in, by hacking furiously away at your keyboard made it look more like "Hanz! Get ze Flamethrower!" Probably just funny in my imagination - but you made me laugh anyway.

Comment: Something is wrong in how you're sending the JSON. It looks like you're serializing the JSON to a string, and then returning it via the API which is then serializing that string to JSON.

Comment: Well well, The question was at start  a no repro, you have get 2 answer. But now this edit make the answer invalid. I have been there and man that's why you should post as mutch as information as you can following the [ask] and always try to provide a code block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String json= "{\"Data\":[{\"AI\":\"(00)103002310000531111\",\"BatchId\":157,\"LogisticLevel\":7,\"ParentId\":-1,\"State\":1,\"SyncState\":-1,\"InternalID\":86996,\"ModifyReason\":null,\"AggregationDate\":\"1900-01-01T00:00:00\",\"CommissioningDate\":\"1900-01-01T00:00:00\",\"DecommissioningDate\":\"1900-01-01T00:00:00\",\"NumberOfChildren\":0,\"RejectCode\":-1,\"ShippingDate\":\"1900-01-01T00:00:00\",\"TotalNumberOfUnits\":1,\"CompanyPrefix\":\"030023\",\"FilterValue\":7,\"PackLevel\":1,\"ReferenceCode\":\"\",\"Schema\":1,\"SerialNumber\":\"1000053111\",\"IsGood\":true,\"Children\":[]}],\"Code\":10,\"Message\":\"Data retrieved\"}";

 dynamic bsObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
 Console.WriteLine(bsObj.ToString());
 Console.WriteLine(bsObj.Data[0].BatchId.ToString());  //157
 Console.WriteLine(bsObj.Code.ToString()); // 10
 Console.WriteLine(bsObj.Message.ToString()); // Data retrieved
```

Comment: What is the ms, `MemoryStream` for ?

Comment: MemoryStream is constructed from this byte array containing the json data. the MemoryStream is used as a backing store for the BinaryReader type, which acts upon the in-memory representation.

Comment: Let me formulate: The `ms` variable is declare and never used. My bad, my English made you think I was asking for a definition of `MemoryStream`.

Comment: oops!!! i forgot to remove ... Sry

Answer (score 3):

Your Json is valid and can be deserialized using JsonConvert:

```
public class Datum
{
    public string AI { get; set; }
    public int BatchId { get; set; }
    public int LogisticLevel { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public int State { get; set; }
    public int SyncState { get; set; }
    public int InternalID { get; set; }
    public object ModifyReason { get; set; }
    public DateTime AggregationDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime CommissioningDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime DecommissioningDate { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfChildren { get; set; }
    public int RejectCode { get; set; }
    public DateTime ShippingDate { get; set; }
    public int TotalNumberOfUnits { get; set; }
    public string CompanyPrefix { get; set; }
    public int FilterValue { get; set; }
    public int PackLevel { get; set; }
    public string ReferenceCode { get; set; }
    public int Schema { get; set; }
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public bool IsGood { get; set; }
    public List<object> Children { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Datum> Data { get; set; }
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(
    "{\"Data\":[{\"AI\":\"(00)103002310000531111\",\"BatchId\":157,\"LogisticLevel\":7,\"ParentId\":-1,\"State\":1,\"SyncState\":-1,\"InternalID\":86996,\"ModifyReason\":null,\"AggregationDate\":\"1900-01-01T00:00:00\",\"CommissioningDate\":\"1900-01-01T00:00:00\",\"DecommissioningDate\":\"1900-01-01T00:00:00\",\"NumberOfChildren\":0,\"RejectCode\":-1,\"ShippingDate\":\"1900-01-01T00:00:00\",\"TotalNumberOfUnits\":1,\"CompanyPrefix\":\"030023\",\"FilterValue\":7,\"PackLevel\":1,\"ReferenceCode\":\"\",\"Schema\":1,\"SerialNumber\":\"1000053111\",\"IsGood\":true,\"Children\":[]}],\"Code\":10,\"Message\":\"Data retrieved\"}"

).Dump();
```